# Problem deploying Front End to Render ELIFECYCLE errno 9

Tags: reactjs, deployment, frontend, web-deployment, mern

I am trying for the first time to deploy Front End part of my MERN Stack Project. It is not finished, but i am trying to know if i can do it :D You can see front end part on https://github.com/vLaD1m1r99/Platform-Client-Render
This is the error note i am getting, and i cant figure out why, also i think i have deployed back end fine, but i am not sure at that either, but it is topic for another time:

```
Feb 4 05:09:34 PM  ==> Using Python version: 3.7.10
Feb 4 05:09:38 PM  ==> Running build command 'npm run build'...
Feb 4 05:09:38 PM  
Feb 4 05:09:38 PM  > mern-stack-client@0.1.0 build /opt/render/project/src
Feb 4 05:09:38 PM  > react-scripts --openssl-legacy-provider build
Feb 4 05:09:38 PM  
Feb 4 05:09:38 PM  node: bad option: --openssl-legacy-provider
Feb 4 05:09:38 PM  npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
Feb 4 05:09:38 PM  npm ERR! errno 9
Feb 4 05:09:38 PM  npm ERR! mern-stack-client@0.1.0 build: `react-scripts --openssl-legacy-provider build`
Feb 4 05:09:38 PM  npm ERR! Exit status 9
Feb 4 05:09:38 PM  npm ERR!
Feb 4 05:09:38 PM  npm ERR! Failed at the mern-stack-client@0.1.0 build script.
Feb 4 05:09:38 PM  npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
Feb 4 05:09:38 PM  
Feb 4 05:09:38 PM  npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
Feb 4 05:09:38 PM  npm ERR!     /opt/render/.cache/_logs/2023-02-04T16_09_38_620Z-debug.log
Feb 4 05:09:38 PM  ==> Build failed
```

I tried to make some changes, clean package.json, but i am still not sure what is the problem.